# SQL Log Shipping Firewall settings

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I'm attempting to setup log shipping between two differnet domains.  When I attempt to connect to the secondary server instance the primary server fails to connect.  If I turn off the windows firewall on the secondary server then I'm able to connect.

I have opened up the following tcp ports on the secondary server windows firewall
1433, 1434, 137, 139, 445

I have opened up the following udp ports on the secondary server windows firewall
137, 138

Are there any other ports or firewall settings that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to connect to a secondary instance on the server.  If I use the primary instance this appears to work.  Is there a way to use the secondary instance?  I have the secondary instance port open but it is not of course using 1433.

Answer (score 0):

The server needed to be added to the LMHosts file so that SQL Server could resolve the path to the directory that the Transaction logs were being saved to.